# Adding Emoticons to app

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I have created a small chat app using pyside. I want to add 'Emoticons'(smileys) options for users to chat. I haven't getting any material on internet. I will be really grateful if someone helps to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Qt supports a thing called SVG font. It is a font where every letter is a colored vector image. You can use these in text fields and webkit.

Comment: Thnx for taking interest. But i m quite new to these things. Can you elaborate more, please?

Comment: No, never used it myself.